# Multiple circle progress in one page

Tags: html, css, frontend, progress-bar

I created a circular progress bar with CSS, HTML, and JavaScript (based on fiddle code), but I'm not an expert in JS, and I could not figure out how I can solve this problem.

The problem is that I want more than one bar, but when I duplicate this code below, it does not work (only the first bar appears).

I tried to duplicate the HTML and the JS code too, and rewrite the span id ("procent" in this example), but it didn't work.

I also tried with the each(function(), but I have not succeeded.

**The javascript code is the following:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
    c = can.getContext('2d');

  var posX = can.width / 2,
    posY = can.height / 2,
    fps = 2000 / 150,
    procent = 0,
    oneProcent = 360 / 6289,
    result = oneProcent * 6289;


  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();

  function arcMove() {
    var deegres = 0;
    var acrInterval = setInterval(function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(posX, posY, 140, (Math.PI / 180) * 270, (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + 360));
      c.strokeStyle = '#55c800';
      c.lineWidth = '5';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#55c800';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc(posX, posY, 140, (Math.PI / 180) * 270, (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + deegres));
      c.stroke();
      if (deegres >= result) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);



  }


}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <span id="procent">6289</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you want it to repeat itself once it reaches the starting point?

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to duplicate the code, as obviously the code you have given works OK.

Comment: @InSync no, i want new circles with different content.

Comment: @AHaworth the code above is working, this is the original code, when one circle works.
I copied all the code, and rename the "procent" words to procent2 (in HTML too), example, but didn't work.

Comment: But that seems to mean that you aren’t picking up all the different canvases that you have on the page. Please show us the code you have used, including the revised HTML.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you go through each step of the original code understanding exactly what it does, particularly the fact that you will need a different canvas to be drawn for each circle. Then learn about picking up not just one canvas as is done in the example code, but using something like querySelectorAll to pick up all the canvases and step through them setting each one up as required (colors and percentage).